# pinch to zoom graph chart in the chart frame only SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to make my custom linear graph chart zoomable(?). after research I used pinch to zoom( MagnificationGesture in swiftUI) to make it. now my graph can zoom out or in. but when I zoom out it cover the whole scene which is I never want. I want my graph only zoom out in the chart frame(I mean limited area of screen) only. How can I solve this problem?

```
@State var scale : CGFloat = 1.0

let frame = CGSize(width: 350, height: 500)

public init(data: [Int], style: ChartStyle = Styles.lineChartStyleOne ){
    self.style = style
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .center){
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Spacer()
            GeometryReader{ geometry in
                
                Line(data: self.data, frame: .constant(geometry.frame(in: .local)), touchLocation: self.$touchLocation, showIndicator: self.$showIndicatorDot)
                    .offset(x: 15,y:0)
  
                Legend(data: self.data, frame: .constant(geometry.frame(in: .local)), hideHorizontalLines: .constant(false))
                   
                RangeLineView(data: self.data, frame: .constant(geometry.frame(in: .local)))
                RangeView(data: self.data, frame: .constant(geometry.frame(in: .local)))
            }
            .frame(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
                .scaleEffect(scale)
                .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    self.scale = value.magnitude
                }
                
                  )
            
            .offset(x: 0, y: 0)
            
        }.frame(width: self.style.chartFormSize.width, height: self.style.chartFormSize.height)
    }
}
```

[image: this is what happen after zoom out. graph cover whole scene. I want it zoom out and show in only original graph frame box]

Comment: There is a bar chart library, you can check it out as well https://github.com/dawigr/BarChart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figure it out my self...

.clipped(Rectangle())

simple but it will do that magic.